# Android Studio Counter TextView Field not updating

Tags: java, android

Assuming Imports and Stuff

Im trying to build a simple Calorie Counter, but having a trouble displaying 
 the number of calories. I also want it to add to the previous input.. 
 for instance if the user enters 500, 400, 300 the total in the TextField 
 should be 1200.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CalorieAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="rav_singh.caloriecounter.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <TextView
        android:text="Current Calories "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/caloriesNeeded"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calCount"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calCount"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Add "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calorieAdd"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/caloriesNeeded"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/calorieinput"
        android:hint="Add Calories "
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/caloriesNeeded"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/caloriesNeeded"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

     EditText input;
     TextView calTotal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calCount);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calorieinput);

        Button calorieAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calorieAdd);
        calTotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Float n1 = Float.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
                calTotal.setText(Float.toString(n1));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> previous input.. for instance if the user enters 500, 400, 300 the
>   total in the TextField should be 1200

Add both TextView and EditText data before updating counter in TextView like:

```
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 
            float n0 = Float.parseFloat(calTotal.getText().toString());
            float n1 = Float.parseFloat(input.getText().toString());
            calTotal.setText(Float.toString(n0+n1));
        }
```

Also added empty check for EditText before parsing value to Float to avoid `NumberFormatException`  Exception.

Comment: If the user were to close the app, will the number still be what it was last ? Or will the app reset

Comment: @RaviSingh: reset. `will the number still be what it was last` for this need to use [SharedPreferences](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Comment: Getting it to work Thank You... What about resetting the app every day what do you recommend I use for that ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(input.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)
     float n1 = Float.parseFloat(input.getText().toString());
```

instead of:

```
Float n1 = Float.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
```